# Most efficient way to iterate through nested lists containg a complex object

Tags: c#

I"m building a C# CSV file comparer.

I have three classes, two of them contains a List of the child classes...

```
public class ExcelSchema  
{
    public string SchemaName { get; set; }
    public List<RowObjects> RowObjects { get; set; }
}

public class RowObjects  
 {
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
    public List<RowObject> RowObjectList { get; set; }

}

public class RowObject
{

    public int ColNum { get; set; }
    public int RowNum { get; set; }
    public string ColLetter { get; set; }
    public string rowValue { get; set; }
    public string CellValue { get; set; }
}
```

Once the collections are populated, what is the most efficient and best method for iterating through each object in the child list? What is the best way to comparer it against another parent class?

-Thanks

Comment: It is hard to come up with a "best" solution when you haven't stated the end goal. What is the end goal? Compare in what way?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more explicit..  I'm populating My ExcelSchema Object with cells from an excel CVS file.   My plan is to populate two of these objects with two separate CVS files and compare the different cells (RowObject).

Comment: Compare them how? By checking if they are equal? If so you would just need to create a hash and compare them.

Comment: I added an answer, but I am not really confident in its thoroughness, despite my trying to cover most angles. A lot of it will come down to what you want to compare, how you want to compare it, and how much overhead you are willing to sacrifice. As @MattRowland said, you haven't really stated your real goal for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you want to compare? The `ExcelSchema` class? You could write a comparer method on that class that iterates through the collection and compares each of the items. That is probably going to be the only real way to do this. Can the objects be different, but the item collection the same? You could create a hash of the items and compare that for equality if you wanted.

Depending on how you want to judge equality on the `RowObject` items (what determines equality, `ColNum`? `ColNum` + `RowNum`?...) depending upon how "equal" you want the items to be, you could approach it several different ways... I would definitely add a `.Equals(RowObject)` method to the `RowObject` class, and an `Equals(ExcelSchema)` method to the `ExcelSchema` class. How you code that, is up to you, again depending on how you want to judge that equality.

It could be as simple as creating a string concatenation of all the items in the `RowObject` and comparing them to each item in the list, or creating a string out of all of the items in the list and comparing that, you could reduce that to a hash of the string concatenation. Or you could grab the first `n` letters of each property in the class, and compare that. Again, all dependent on the level of equality or "sameness" you want and the amount of overhead spent comparing that you are willing to spend.